# How to hide axes in multiple plot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, axis

What is wrong for this code for hiding right and top axes, please?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,3))
fig1 = plt.subplot(121)
fig2 = plt.subplot(122)

# Set width of axes
for figures in [fig1, fig2]:
    # Removing axis 
    for side in ['right','top']:
        ax.spines[side].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

This works for non-multiple plot:

```
for side in ['right','top']:
    ax.spines[side].set_visible(False)
```

**EDITED CODE:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,3))
fig1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$k$')
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$\omega$', rotation='horizontal')

fig2 = plt.subplot(122)

sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `for ax in [fig1, fig2]`.. Though `fig1` and `fig2` are misleading variable names here.

Comment: Or use seaborn: `sns.despine()`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: `fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,3))` and get rid of the extraneous `plt.subplot` calls. then `For ax in axs.ravel()`.

Comment: Thank you and how to control ax in individuals plots, please? I added EDIT part to my question.

Comment: Get rid of the `fig1, ax1 = plt.subplot(121)`. If you want, `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,3))`

Comment: Thank you, I gave edited code to my question. Why the labels are not now at the end of the axis, please?

Comment: Side note, but get rid of `for figures in [fig1, fig2]:` and `for side in ['right', top']:`. All you need to remove the spines is `sns.despine()`, called without looping.

Comment: Use `ax1.set_xlabel` and `ax2.set_xlabel` instead of `plt.xlabel` and similarly for the y-labels.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223772/discussion-between-elena-greg-and-bigben).

Comment: What is wrong with this, please?
`fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(10,10))` It gives an error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 2)' It works when I give nrows = 6, but it is not a desired.